# My icon inside TextInput does not work on Android devices but works on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have this weird problem where my icon functionality does not work on Android but works on iOS and I'm puzzled.

Basically what I would like to achieve is to press on the icon with eye and show or hide password when user is signing in.

```
 <Controller
        name="password1"
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
          <>
            <TextInput
              label="Password"
              secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
              returnKeyType="next"
              textContentType="password"
              onChangeText={onChange}
              value={value}
              onBlur={() => trigger(name)}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              testID="password-input"
              error={errors?.password1?.message}
              right={
                <RNPTextInput.Icon
                  icon={showPassword ? EyeOff : EyeOn}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
                  }}
                />
              }
            />
          </>
        )}
      />
```

What I did try is to play around and replace the RNTextInput.Icon to TouchableOpacity but ain't workin.

SEND HALP
RN IS SO WEIRD SOMETIMES I LOVE IT

Comment: Is TextInput from react-native-paper?

Comment: yes it is indeed

Comment: If RNPTextInput is a custom implementation, the problem must be there. TextInput.Icon works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using this code

```html
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput
              label="Password"
              secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
              returnKeyType="next"
              textContentType="password"
              onChangeText={onChange}
              value={value}
              onBlur={() => trigger(name)}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              testID="password-input"
              error={errors?.password1?.message}
        
            />
               <Icon
                  icon={showPassword ? EyeOff : EyeOn}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
                  }}
                />
                
 </View>
```

you can adjust the styling accordingly

Comment: where is the Icon imported from?

Comment: you can use Icon package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons or use a pressable image